# When I try and run command "pip help" it gives me an error

Tags: python, pip

When I want to install anything using pip I get an error saying "Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Python\Python.exe" "C:\Python\Scripts\pip.exe"'. even when I use the command "pip help" I get the same error

Images of error:
[error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fj2b6.png)
[error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8zKq.png)

Comment: Looks like you don't have PIP installed properly

Comment: i got it from 10.4 automatically, is there a way to repair it?

Comment: Does `python -m pip --help` do anything?

Comment: yes it shows me all the cmds

Comment: Ok that good just prefix all pip commands with `python -m` then

Comment: Your system seems to have a file named something like `pip.cmd` that issues an incorrect console command. If you type the command complained of at a console prompt you will get a similar error message. You need to find what file or registry setting is grabbing your invocation of `pip` and doing something weird with it.

Comment: First thing to try: `where pip`.